# How does this recursion and back tracking work in LeetCode?

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion

This function which will print the nodes of a linked list in reverse:

```
void recur(ListNode head) {
    if(head == null) return; 
    recur(head.next);
    tmp.add(head.val);
}
```

If the list is **1 -> 2 -> 3** then `tmp` (an `ArrayList`) will add the value of the node.

At last, we can get a list `[3, 2, 1]` via printing `tmp`. However, I do not know why it works. Why does the `recur` function loop to the last node then add the values in reverse order?

Comment: Hey, welcome! For future reference, please avoid posting an image of your code in the question. Instead, copy your code directly into the question (marked up as code). Thanks!

Comment: Got it! Thanks, man!

Answer (score 1):

I think this flow diagram may help you.

[image]

As you can see from the diagram the head.value is added to the tmp list only when end of the linked list is reached. i.e . head becames null

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty much simple, let's consider the `[1 -> 2]` node with two ListNode and we want to reverse with you function:

```
void recur(ListNode head) {
    if (head == null) return;
    recur(head.next);
    tmp.add(head.val);
}
```

1. On the first stem, the head will point to `1` value, this check `if (head == null)` will return `false` since head node is not null.
2. Then we call the same function `recur` but for the next node with value `2`, and execution of `recur` start over but with node `2` as a head node. We again check `if (head == null)` -> `false`, same reason, head is not null here.
3. Then we call the same function `recur` but for the next node which is null `head.next -> null`, since there are no nodes anymore after node `2`. We check `if (head == null)`, but now we have `true`, the current node, meaning there are no nodes left after and we can't go further calling `recur()` again. So, we stop the recursion with a `return` statement.
4. Now, we return again to step #2 and continue execution, because the execution of `recur(head.next)` ends by `return` statement. That means, this node is the last one, and we put its value to the `tmp`. And the execution of `recur` for ListNode `2` ends, since there are no code lines after.
5. Now, we return again to step #1 and do the same logic as described in step 4. Since `recur` for node `2` ends its execution we proceed and put value `1` to `tmp` array.

---

`if (head == null) return;` - this check, called recursion `base case`, meaning `when we need to end execution and exit?`, without it recursion will go infinitely.

We dig to the end of the ListNode and then return again to the top.
To be able to put ListNode value to the `tmp` we need first put next value to the `tmp` and so on.

I hope, I explained more accurately and its more clear for you now.

Comment: Your logic is amazing! Thanks!